# Why an installed package has no affect for sudoed user?

Tags: debian, root, xfce, thunar

I've installed Debian 10 with Xfce DE.  Thunar app is the default file manager.

On `Edit > Preferences > Advance` Thunar shows a warning message. This message is about gvfs dependencies to activate some Thunar improvements. So I install two packages: **gvfs-backends** and **gvfs-fuse**, and warning message dissapears.

But, when I run Thunar with sudo, the same warning message appears. I am really bewildered, because I have installed **gvfs-backends** and **gvfs-fuse** for all system. I assume that when I install any package via `sudo apt install ...` the changes apply for all users, even root user. So, What happened here? Why root Thunar still shows warning message?

Comment: Please provide the exact warning message you receive.

Comment: I fixed many grammar errors in your post. Please don't use abbreviation, as it makes the information density very high, and hard to fix errors.

Answer (score 0):

Now I use Debian 10 (XFCE). I find XFCE very solid, and I can use trash can and removable media without problems, so I don't worry about that 'warning' message.

I share with you a image of the 'warning' message but in spanish, maybe can be help you and somebody can explain why root user keeps show it.

[image]

PS. Quick translation: 'It seems that gvfs is not available, important functionalities including support for the bin, removable devices and location navigation will not work.'

Comment: This does not quite answer the question of why the warning occurs when the user is root but not otherwise.